# Slow Postgres query with jsonb and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

We have a Postgres table which stores documents analysis as jsonb. There are currently around 100k entries with this table and I'm trying to query the results – unfortunately, the query is much slower than expected (> 4 seconds). Caching and/or materialized views are not a solution IMO since the user has a bunch of filters (e.g. date/category) and therefore every query will be slighlty different.

Here's the query ...

```sql
SELECT r.key AS key,
       SUM((r.value->>'counter')::int) AS count_key,
       COUNT(*) AS count_documents,
       json_agg(json_build_object(
           'date', data_reportfile.date::date,
           'count_key', (r.value->>'counter')::int )
       ) AS dates
  FROM data_reportfile,
       jsonb_each(analysis_result->'results') r
 WHERE data_reportfile.date >= '1960-1-1'
   AND data_reportfile.analysis_done IS TRUE
   AND r.value->>'category' = 'general'
 GROUP BY r.key
 ORDER BY count_documents DESC
 LIMIT 20;
```

And here's the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...

```
  Limit  (cost=42442.85..42442.86 rows=1 width=80) (actual time=4338.407..4343.240 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=42442.85..42442.86 rows=1 width=80) (actual time=4338.406..4338.413 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 10002kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=42442.83..42442.84 rows=1 width=80) (actual time=4324.406..4332.789 rows=2704 loops=1)
               Group Key: r.key
               ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..41071.38 rows=49871 width=68) (actual time=0.699..759.060 rows=911509 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 3
                     Workers Launched: 3
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..35084.28 rows=16087 width=68) (actual time=0.421..2317.619 rows=227877 loops=4)
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on data_reportfile  (cost=0.00..10792.90 rows=16087 width=291) (actual time=0.016..25.494 rows=12461 loops=4)
                                 Filter: ((analysis_done IS TRUE) AND (date >= '1960-01-01'::date))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 3901
                           ->  Function Scan on jsonb_each r  (cost=0.01..1.50 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.171..0.179 rows=18 loops=49843)
                                 Filter: ((value ->> 'category'::text) = 'general'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 8
 Planning time: 0.239 ms
 Execution time: 4353.262 ms
```

I'm not exactly sure, but it seems that the grouping is quite expensive. I guess that an index doesn't help much here (an index for `date` is already defined). I already tweaked some Postgres settings (`work_mem`, `shared_buffers`) without any noticeable effect.

Any idea what I could try at this point? Or do I just have to live with the slow query, because of what I'm trying to achieve.

**UPDATE 1 (Sample Data):**

This is an example of the column `analysis_result`.

```
{
  "country": "FRA",
  "docInfo": {},
  "results": {
    "FRA": {
      "counter": 6,
      "category": "geographic",
      "positions": [
        "26, 21, 65, 71",
        "28, 23, 58, 64",
        "93, 68, 9, 15",
        "106, 79, 160, 166",
        "158, 117, 10, 16",
        "158, 117, 47, 53"
      ],
      "sentences": [],
      "sentiment": [
        "0.0, 0.902, 0.098, 0.4404",
        "0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0",
        "0.041, 0.959, 0.0, -0.128",
        "0.047, 0.799, 0.154, 0.5563",
        "0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0"
      ]
    },
    "Debt": {
      "counter": 2,
      "category": "general",
      "positions": [
        "161, 119, 15, 19",
        "166, 121, 15, 19"
      ],
      "sentences": [],
      "sentiment": [
        "0.172, 0.828, 0.0, -0.3612",
        "0.179, 0.619, 0.203, 0.1779"
      ]
    }
  },
  "docPages": 12,
  "language": "en",
  "counter_words": 1382,
  "counter_tokens": 3591,
  "counter_sentences_final": 123,
  "counter_sentences_total": 169
}
```

**Update 2 (Result):**

And here's what I'm trying to get ... it is basically a list of keywords with counters per date (e.g. year).

```
[
  {
    "key": "Risk",
    "count_key": 283522,
    "count_documents": 22298,
    "dates": [
      {
          "date": "2021",
          "count_key": 228615
      },
      {
          "date": "2020",
          "count_key": 4691
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Debt",
    "count_key": 283522,
    "count_documents": 22298,
    "dates": [
      {
          "date": "2021",
          "count_key": 228615
      },
      {
          "date": "2020",
          "count_key": 4691
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks strange to me that you first expand the JSON column, just to aggregate it back afterwards

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not able to group by `r.key` if I don't expand the json, right? So it's actually expand > group > aggregate. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you showed us some sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the sample data. Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the version?

Comment: @jjanes Tested with both 10.18 and 11.13.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah computing that giant agg keyed to 2704 values (from 911509 rows), just to throw all but 20 away, is a lot of work.  And indexes won't help as you process nearly all the data anyway.

You see every query is different due to "a bunch of filters (e.g. date/category)", but it looks like there is only one meaningful category in your sample data, and what can you possibly do with that date which needs a recomputed jsonb_agg for each different one?

Comment: The user can filter by `date` (which is an attribute with `data_reportfile`, not part of the JSON) and `category` (see sample data). The date-filter can range from a single day to a range between 1960 and today.